# ASP.NET MVC takes long time in login page in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, google-chrome, iis-express

I Have a `Route` that is in the format:

```
http://localhost/SocialNetworkWeb/Home/Index
```

When I press `login` in any other browser it works fine but in Chrome it takes too long.

Is there any problem with `ASP.NET MVC3` & Chrome working together or maybe IIS Express?

Comment: Is the problem only with the login page or is it slow for every page in Chrome?

Comment: Insert a breakpoint in the method index in debug mode, and check if the same error occurs when it is requested by chrome.

Comment: Is it only slow the first time you access the login page? The first time it is accessed it creates the database to handle the membership and roles.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back, I think it was caused by an extension. Try disabling them to see if it makes any difference? In my case it happened with all requests though, but can't hurt to try.

Comment: @Trax72 that was my problem, thanks for your time :D.

Answer (score 2):

The browser shouldn't matter as all.

What kind of login is setup? Forms authentication, windows auth, etc?

Load the site while running Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/  and compare time/requests between browsers, there should be nothing via Forms Auth that differentiates it but Fiddler should give you a better idea - off the top of my head there's no browser specific issue coming to mind.

Comment: The problem was in HP simple pass that weirdly crash every time i try to login it takes too long to validate & finally crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the "TrueSuite Website Logon Extension" was the problem and once i disabled it every thing was back to normal, Thanks for your time everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into an issue like this but in MVC 4.  I needed to set up assembly redirects in my web.config file.  They look like this for MVC 4.

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```